# Roleplaying Chaotic Evil the wrong way?

Tags: dnd-5e

So, I'm roleplaying a CE sorcerer, and my DM insists on me not roleplaying it properly. I'm trying to not make my character Stupid Evil and just stab everyone's throats as they cross my path; instead, I prefer going around provoking people, intimidating, tricking and cheating my way through everything. My character's "train of thought" is pretty much wiping all 'unworthy' evil to up everyone's game, and try to incite everyone to be evil.

Right now, we're running Curse of Strahd, and I'm going around recruiting Strahd's cultists/followers giving them 2 options: serve me, or die. Dracula is going to die, and I'm going to become the lord of the land.

I don't quite know if I'm actually doing it right (thought I was), if I'm not, what could I change to better roleplay a proper CE character?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is probably off-topic, see also this meta: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/what-kinds-of-alignment-questions-are-on-topic

Comment: @Erik How can it be off-topic if it's about roleplaying in a "role-playing games" site?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. Erik's meta link explains how alignment questions don't fit our site's Q&A structure very well; not everything about RPGs can be discussed usefully here. If you want to discuss RPGs in a less structured format, [we keep a list of sites which can augment the Stack Exchange's limitations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4398).

Comment: While I agree this question as it stands is probably off topic here, it's an interesting question of GM vs. player expectations, and I think it could be edited to avoid the "what's the right way to roleplay" conflict and favor the "how can my GM and I get on the same page on this particular issue?" without just ending in links to the Same Page Tool.

Comment: Questions about how one "should" roleplay alignments are ones we close because they're wholly a matter of opinion. It doesn't help that particular behaviours or individuals can easily be attributed to multiple alignments, and different alignments use non-mutually-exclusive descriptions. Since there is no correct or verifiably best answer, they don't fit our format well.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what your DM thinks is correct? It might be possible to provide an answer more related to your specific group's dynamic on what's acceptable CE for your group rather than tell you the 'right' way to play CE in general. Personally, I've played evil campaigns before and there's definitely a right way and a wrong way to do things.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical He pretty much wants me to go around murdering everything on sight, or being a bit more like the Joker.

Comment: @user39417 You may be able to get this question reopened if you describe what your DM thinks CE is, what you think it is, and what the table thinks it is. I'm also curious if a Session 0 was done for this game and whether the topic was discussed; right now it seems like it wasn't.

Comment: This actually has an answer supported by the book.

Comment: What you describe as your DM's stance is silly, but *would* fit chaotic evil. Creating your own rules and abiding by them isn't the most chaotic approach to things, so a shift towards neutral evil may solve the argument to everyone's satisfaction.